# How to call an object created in another function

Tags: c++, qt, function

I want to call an object of class QLabel in another function . I know this is basic C++ ,but its confusing in Qt .

in my mainwindow.cpp i have created a function

```
void createlbl(){

QLabel *lbl1 = new QLabel("Hello");

}

void Mainwindow :: resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *evt){


}
```

i need to call the label object (lbl1) in the resizeEvent function to resize it.
I also need to call the object in other functions in my program.
I tried different ways but i am not getting the right way to call it and use in different functions.
Please tell me what parameters should i pass and how i should call the class or the function in which the class is created to use in different functions.

Thank you

Comment: This is basic C++, and it has nothing to do with Qt.

Comment: [Member variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Member_variable).

Comment: Declare him in header, to be visible, instatiate him in constructor and use him in your event.

Comment: is createlbl() actually Mainwindow ::createlbl() ?

Answer (score 1):

This is basic C++, check this tutorial [Class Tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/).

Create your QLabel* as a private variable in your header file, add a getter if you want to make it accesible to another classes and make it public:

```
public:
     QLabel* label() const { return _label; }
...    
private:
     QLabel* _label;
```

In your cpp file init your QLabel* by calling your createlbl() function before using it, lets call it in your class constructor to avoid null pointers. Now, just use it in your resizeEvent function:

```
void Mainwindow :: resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *evt){
     label()->setText("Hey, i'm here!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume QLabel is a `member`of your Mainwindow. You should also declare it like this.

.h:

```
class Mainwindow
{
  public:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *evt); //Q_DECL_OVERRIDE ?
  private:
    QLabel    mLabel; //a member of MainWindow class, also no pointer
}
```

.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow():
  mLabel()
{
  //mLabel will be available inside every function of "MainWindow"
}
MainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *evt)
{
  mLabel.setText("Done.");
}
```

For myself, I try to avoid pointers if possible. Its much easier and you dont have to think about avoiding memory leaks.

Comment: When you add widget to layout of other widget it becomes it's child and qt takes care of it's deletion.

Comment: Sure, but you can also do it without pointers. I just thought it could cause bad habits to alwasy use pointers.